# VGA recognition issue while trying to use old windows on a virtual machine

Tags: windows, graphics-card, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation, vga

I installed Windows ME as a guest OS on a virtual machine (two different software: Microsoft VM 2007 & VMWare ver. 10.0) hosted by a 64-bit Windows 7 (Intel Core i5, 8.0 GiB RAM). Problem is that Windows ME uses **Generic 16 colors VGA** as my display adapter and it will not satisfy my requirement, because this game needs a 3D 16bit VGA. I tried to install random VGAs through WinME's device manager. It presented a long list of brands and model and I picked some of them. It did not accept any.

I am completey aware that it is impossible to have WinME to recognize my **AMD ATI HD 5450** graphic card. Is there any way to fool WinME (or virtual machine?!) to use one of branded VGAs that are defined in Windows ME's database?

Comment: No, you cannot fool the VM into having having hardware that doesn’t exist

Comment: @Ramhound What am I supposed to do to have a 3D VGA there?

Comment: Doesn't VirtualPC emulate a "S3 Trio"? That's fairly weak but still certainly not a "generic 16 colors" one.

Comment: You can use a different hypervisor but without a card that supports Windows ME you won’t be able to install drivers which are required to accomplish what you want.  Which of course is the reason Windows ME really shouldn’t be used in 2018. You are obviously trying to run a -6-not application.

Comment: @grawity No! Just a boring 'Generic VGA'

Comment: @Ramhound retrogaming is probably one of the few good reasons to run windows 9x in this day and age.

Comment: @Ramhound I know it is 2018 & Windows ME does not probably belong to this age. Thanks for mentioning.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Better solutions then VMs depending on the game.  If I knew what was being attempted, might be able to offer a better solution :$

Answer (score 0):

Don't install random video drivers in a VM, this will only make things worse.
If "VM 2007" means Virtual PC 2007, all you need to do is install the VPC Additions (included with VPC 2007) in Windows ME VM.
Similarly, with VMware 10 (workstation, I assume) you again just need to install VMware's tools in Windows ME, also included with the program.